# How to map from a particular index and then stop at after a particular index

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

I am trying to make a react list and i am stuck because in my state there are 50 object in a array and i only want to render 10 object i don't know how to stop the rendering after particular index can anyone help me here is my code of what i am trying to do
I am using material ui

```
const AnimeResults = ({ search: { animelist, isAnimeLoaded } }) => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    return isAnimeLoaded ? (
        <Spinner />
    ) : (
            <List dense className={classes.root}>
                {animelist.map((anime, index) => {
                    const labelId = `checkbox-list-secondary-label-${index}`;
                    return (
                        <ListItem key={anime.mal_id} button>
                            <ListItemAvatar>
                                <Avatar
                                    alt={`Avatar n°${anime + 1}`}
                                    src={anime.image_url}
                                />
                            </ListItemAvatar>
                            <ListItemText id={labelId} primary={`${anime.title}`} />
                            <ListItemSecondaryAction>
                                <div>+</div>
                            </ListItemSecondaryAction>
                        </ListItem>
                    );
                })}
            </List>
        );
}
```

Hope i am able to explain myself can anyone help me please i am stuck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

`animelist.slice(0, 10).map((anime, index) => {`

you can use `slice` to get the first `X` amount (in your case; 10) then `map` over that array

Comment: oh that was quick that will work
Thanks that worked

Comment: yeh try that and see if it works for you and what you want

Comment: @Arun no worries. mark it correct if you get a chance, thanks

Comment: yes i will it is showing 10 min before i can add this as correct :D

Answer (score 1):

`.map` loops over entire array called upon, so `slice` it before

```
animelist.slice(0,10).map(...)
```

or more dynamically with `slice(x, x+ 10)`

Comment: Thank You That worked for me will try the dynamic one for sure